# Find a value of all occurrences from the json string in c#

Tags: c#, json, search

I have a JSON object with some data and I want to get all the values of each occurrence of specific key name. Is there any predefined method to search for a key in JSON object for all occurrences or need to write user defined method?

Sample Json

```
[{"id":"23","name":"sunny","className":"2","class" :{"className":"1","class2" :{"className":"3","class" :{"className":"4"}}}}]
```

Comment: Please provide some more detail and sample data that you look for.

Comment: I want to find the value of key name 'xyz' which can be present at anywhere in json object and any no of times.

Comment: Is you json data has nested object or array items ? It would be nice if you put some data in your question. It will help me and other to understand your question well.

Comment: Please provide sample JSON to help clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, My json object is nested. and the key might present at any level in my json object,

Comment: this is sample json object and I want to get all the values with key 'className' [{"id":"23","name":"sunny","className":"2","class" :{"className":"1","class2" :{"className":"3","class" :{"className":"4"}}}}]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved with LINQ to JSON by using the `SelectTokens` method with a recursive path `..className`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

        // You would use this because you have an array.
        // JArray jObject = JArray.Parse(jsonArray);

        // .. - recursive descent
        var classNameTokens = jObject.SelectTokens("..className"); 
        var values = classNameTokens.Select(x => (x as JValue).Value);
    }

    static string jsonString = @"{'id':'23','name':'sunny','className':'2','class' :{'className':'1','class2' :{'className':'3','class' :{'className':'4'}}}}";
    static string jsonArray = @"[{'id':'23','name':'sunny','className':'2','class' :{'className':'1','class2' :{'className':'3','class' :{'className':'4'}}}}]";
}
```

References:

[Json.NET - Documentation - Parsing JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)

[Json.NET 6.0 Release 1 - JSONPath and F# Support](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/02/01/json-net-6-0-release-1-%E2%80%93-jsonpath-and-f-support)

[JSONPath expressions](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2)

Comment: In c# I have a string with JSON data, I want to retrieve all the values of key with name 'className'.
I will send two parameters JSON string and key name and I want list of values with key name 'className'

Comment: mhmm... sorry, I'm afraid I don't know what you mean now. Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: it is showing error Path returned multiple tokens @t3chb0t

Comment: Can you show me what you created because I didn't have any errors while testing my example?

Comment: var s = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(design);
JArray jObject1 = JArray.Parse(s.ToString());
JObject jObject = (JObject)jObject1[0];
var classNameTokens = jObject.SelectToken("..entityName");
var values = classNameTokens.Select(x => (x as JValue).Value); upto jobject is working fine when I try to get classNameTokens it is showing error path returned multiple tokens and one more note is I change SelectTokens to SelectToken, Shall I need to use SelectTokens, If yes it is showing error

Comment: Yes. You must use SelectTokens because you are interested in multiple results and a recursive search not in the first result found. This is how I understand it.

Comment: Could you post your json-string of s.ToString()? It is not the same as in your first example, right?

Comment: Ten it is showing error, To resolve error, am I supposed to do something?   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'SelectTokens' and no extension method 'SelectTokens' accepting a first argument of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Then I think you might not be using the latest json.net? I tested it with the version 6.0.0.0.

Comment: Upto the jobject it is working fine. It is showing error in selecttokens can you provide solution to update json.net?

Comment: I am using json.net 6.0.6

Comment: There has to be something wrong with your project settings because your code runs in my project without errors.

Comment: can you forward me the code zip file to my mail? this could be great helpful for me. or share through git hub

Comment: [
  {
    "id": "qrtm",
    "title": "samle",
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": "spmg",
        "title": "",
        "selectedConnection": {
          "system": {
            "id": 6408
          },
          "action": {
            "identifier": "Create"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "rnmg",
        "title": "",
        "selectedConnection": {
          "system": {
            "id": 6428
          },
          "action": {
            "identifier": "delete"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
I want to get all the ids in system in selected connecions