# Extract values from json or jarray elements

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON Array like :

```
[
    {
        "type": "type1",
        "id": "id1",
        "properties": 
        {
            "sales": 
            [
                {
                    "name": "name1",
                    "requested_date": "2019-06-28"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "type1",
        "id": "id2",
        "properties": 
        {
            "sales": 
            [
                {
                    "name": "name2",
                    "requested_date": "2019-06-28"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "type1",
        "id": "id3",
        "properties": 
        {
            "sales": 
            [
                {
                    "name": "name3",
                    "requested_date": "2019-06-29"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I want to read through it first to extract all unique values of requested_date, so in this case I would have "2019-06-28", "2019-06-29".

Secondly, I will need to be able to select all entries in regards to a selected value of a specified requested_date.  I already have a POCO for sales, and one for the entire entry but properties is only Dictionary of object, because it can be anything, like in this case it is a sales.

I have my JSON in a `JArray`:

```
var stringCachedAddresses = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cachedAddresses);
var parsedObject = JArray.Parse(stringCachedAddresses);
```

I just don't know how to navigate to the `requested_date` of each entry, to add the value to a list if not already present, maybe some sort of LINQ I can't figure out.

I can get a list of all sales:

```
var parsedProperties = (from f in parsedObject
                        select f["properties"]["sales"]).ToList();
```

How can I read from the `parsedProperties` or directly to only get values of `requested_date`?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Is there a specific error or problem you're running into? If you haven't already done so take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help article on how to ask good questions.

Comment: There are many hundreds of posts here dealing with JSON serialization and parsing.

Comment: Yes but found none with multiple level like this one at least, most of time is very simple Json and very few with selecting values from it like I am looking for.

Comment: *Secondly, I will need to be able to select all entries in regards to a selected value of a specified requested_date.  I already have a POCO for sales...* The preferred format for questions on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so could you break that down into a separate post and show the `Sales` POCO.

Comment: For the first part, if you just want to find all occurrences of `"requested_date"` in your JSON hierarchy, see [Find a value of all occurrences from the json string in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27142884/3744182) or [How do I get a deeply-nested property from JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36324494/3744182), e.g. var `query = parsedObject.SelectTokens("..requested_date")..Select(t => t.ToObject<DateTime>()).Distinct();`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BkAEaP

Comment: What do you mean by `properties is only Dictionary of object, because it can be anything, like in this case it is a sales.`?  This part of your question is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your *POCO for sales* looks like the following:

```
public class Sales
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string requested_date { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can find all `"sales"` objects in your hierarchy with a specified `requested_date` and deserialize them by combining a [jsonpath](/questions/tagged/jsonpath) query with calls to [`JToken.ToObject<Sales>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) to deserialize each selected item:

```
// Your requested date
var requested_date = "2019-06-28";

// Construct a JSONPath query
var pathTemplate = "[*].properties.sales[?(@.requested_date == '{0}')]";
var path = string.Format(pathTemplate, requested_date);

// Query for and deserialize all sales from the specified requested date
var query = parsedObject.SelectTokens(path)
    .Select(t => t.ToObject<Sales>());

// Materialize the query as a list.
var list = query.ToList();
```

Similarly, you can find all distinct `requested_date` values as follows:

```
// Query for all values of requested_date, convert them to strings, and take all distinct values:
var query = parsedObject.SelectTokens("[*].properties.sales[*].requested_date")
    .Select(t => t.ToString()) 
    .Distinct();

// Materialize the query as a list.
var list = query.ToList();
```

Notes:

1. The `*` wildcard operator selects all array elements.
2. The `?(<expression>)` filter operator applies a filter expression (using Json.NET's [filter syntax](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm#SelectTokenJSONPath)) to select specified array elements -- here those with a specified requested date.
3. For an overview of JSONPath syntax see [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).
4. If the name of the property `"sales"` is not fixed, you can use a wildcard for the property name, e.g.:

   ```
   "[*].properties.*[?(@.requested_date == '{0}')]";
   ```

   And

   ```
   "[*].properties.*[*].requested_date"
   ```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GaYSfQ).

Comment: I saw previous example with JSonPath but I couldn't make it work for me, was missing the wildcard use.  Very better solution then what I was using with from select.

Comment: Does the select could work as in SQL and be able to add a count value for each requested_date?

Comment: Here is how I did it : var querySales = parsedObject.SelectTokens("\[*\].properties.sales\[*\] .requested_date").Select(t => t.ToString()).GroupBy(t => t).Select(x => new { requested_date = x.Key, count = x.Count() });

Comment: I just figured out although it works great to return all Sales from a specific requested date, I want the entire entry with type, id, properties returned from a requested_date not just the sale object

Comment: @KaptainJ - the preferred format here is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/344280) so you should probably ask a new question referring back to this one and with a [mcve] showing your JSON and your data model.  I can't really figure out your requirement from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the distinct requested_date, althoug it looks complicated for not much :

```
var parsedObject = JArray.Parse(stringCachedAddresses);
var parsedProperties = (from f in parsedObject
                        select f["properties"]["sales"]);
var parsedForSales = (from s in parsedProperties.Children()["requested_date"]
                      select s).Distinct().ToList();
```

My main issue remains how I extract JSon entries based on that desired requested_date?

Comment: sounds like you might need something like `.ToLookup` (it's similar to Dictionary with multiple values per key). What values would you need per date?